# Dragging div selects text on page (some browsers)

Tags: javascript

Im using the following function to drag a div with a handle.

Problem is that in some browsers when i drag at the same time text is selected and highlighted on the page..

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
function enableDragging (ele) {
    var dragging = dragging || false,
        x, y, Ox, Oy,
        current;
        enableDragging.z = enableDragging.z || 1;
    var grabber = document.getElementById("myHandle");
    grabber.onmousedown = function (ev) {
        ev = ev || window.event;
        var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        current = target.parentElement;
        dragging = true;
        x = ev.clientX;
        y = ev.clientY;
        Ox = current.offsetLeft;
        Oy = current.offsetTop;
        current.style.zIndex = ++enableDragging.z;
        console.log(dragging);

        document.onmousemove = function(ev) {

            ev = ev || window.event;

            //pauseEvent(ev);         
            if (dragging == true) {
                var Sx = ev.clientX - x + Ox,
                    Sy = ev.clientY - y + Oy;
                current.style.top = Sy + "px";
                current.style.left = Sx + "px";
                document.body.focus();
                // prevent text selection in IE
                document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
                // prevent IE from trying to drag an image
                ev.ondragstart = function() { return false; };                  
                return false;   
            }
        }
        document.onmouseup = function(ev) {
            //alert("stop");
            dragging && (dragging = false);
        }
    };
}    

function pauseEvent(e){
    if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble=true;
    e.returnValue=false;
    return false;
}
```

Drag is started by:

```
    var ele = document.getElementById("divWrapper");
    enableDragging(ele);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I forget the second question in your previous post. However, you need to prevent default from `onmouseup` too:

```
document.onmouseup = function(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    dragging && (dragging = false);
    if (ev.preventDefault) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    } else {
        ev.cancelBubble=true;
        ev.returnValue=false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Or simply use your `pauseEvent()` function. Notice, that in your code there's this: `ev.ondragstart = function () {...};`. It's no use to assign the eventhandler to the Event object, rather assign that to the `document` or `document.body`. And also use that `pauseEvent()` in every eventhandler function too.

It looks like it's better to move `document.onselectstart` and `document.ondragstart` to the `onmousedown` handler, since those events have already fired when execution moves to `onmousemove()`.

Comment: Awesome! Now its only selecting text in Firefox, all other browser work. Any ideas how to fix it on FF too? When i move the div around the background text is selected

Comment: Not quite sure i understand what to do :)

Comment: `document.ondragstart = function() { return false; };` : ). Also notice, that this (and `document.onselectstart...`) should be moved to the `mousedown` handler function. And if you want to select things after dragging, you'll need to remove these handlers in `onmouseup()`. My FF doesn't select text after these changes... Did you uncomment `pauseEvent()` calls?

Comment: Still selecting text in FF :/

Comment: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zxuk/2/) works in my FF18.0.2, it doesn't select text while dragging.

Comment: Still selects text in my FF for some reason :/ Browser compatibility gotta love it

Comment: This solved it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211411/handling-text-selection-event-in-firefox-extension-preventing-user-from-selecti

Comment: Ofcourse! I had totally forgotten `user-select`. Just remember, it won't work in older IEs, so you still need those IE hacks in your code : ). Also there was a wrong version of my fiddle in the previous link. I just realized that if there's more text in the draggable, FF will randomly select it.